# openssh: "... disabled because of invalid user", why?

Tags: android, linux, openssh

I'm trying to make openssh work on android phone.
When I'm trying to log in it refuses to accept my key. Here is the related lines of debug log:

```
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method publickey
debug2: userauth_pubkey: disabled because of invalid user
```

Strace shows that it doesn't even look for the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file.
So the question is **how to make root user valid**.

I've created `/etc/passwd` with appropriate root user entry but it didn't help. I don't see any other related files reading in strace output for sshd.

Comment: I've set it to yes, didn't help.

Comment: AFAIK no, "move" is "take from here", "put there", usually somebody with enough reputation points will do it, but you can delete it as well, and ask there. I guess you reloaded sshd? I'm not really familiar with android, not sure how sshd is to be configured on it.

Comment: Googled it, you're right, will now wait for someone who can do that...  Yes, I restarted it every time, all options related to keys are enabled/set.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note that we have a site dedicated to Android: [android.se] If you would like us to move the question to that site (you might get better answers over there), please flag the question for moderator attention and ask for it to be moved :)

Answer (score 1):

Found it! It was incorrect /etc/passwd: root had wrong shell. Here is a line in strace output that showed it:

```
[pid 30439] stat64("/bin/sh", 0xbefb0f10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

(Maybe this is not an answer...)

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by other factors invalidating the user.

In my case, it was an `AllowGroups` restriction set in my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Remember to restart your SSH daemon after updating that file.